# UV Mapping Texture Stretched

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I've been trying to make an even continuation of a pattern that's on the top part of a mesh lower on the side faces, but pattern keeps stretching to the inside. Any ideas how to make the stipes that are marked as red go straight down like green lines?

example below
[image: example below]

Comment: For a simple stripe texture you could try the following. Top orthographic view > U > Project From View. Then in the UV editor, select all and scale up the UV's as required.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog You should propose that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. In **Top Orthographic** view (<kbd>7</kbd>), Edit mode with all selected > <kbd>U</kbd> > **Project from View**.
2. In the UV editor, scale and position the UV's as required.

[image]